# Gutter spacing between responsive columns in Bootstrap5

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-5

I'm working with columns in a Django app using Bootstrap for styling.
I have been able to use classes to produce a responsive configuration which stacks vertically beyond a specified breakpoint.

I now want to introduce a space or gutter between the columns that is maintained when the columns are stacked vertically.

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center" style="margin-top: -100px;">

     <!-- LEFT -->
     <div class="col-md-4 border rounded bg-light">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
           <h5 class="text-center"> Some text here </h5>
        </div>
        <br>
     </div>

     <!-- RIGHT -->
     <div class="col-md-4 border rounded bg-white">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
           <h3 class="text-center"> Some text here</h3>
           <h2 class="text-center">Some text here</h2>
           <p class="text-center" style="font-size: 11px;">Some text here</p>
        </div>
     </div>
     <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Normal sizing**
[image]

**Responsive sizing**
[image]

**Desired outcome normal**
[image]
**Desired outcome responsive**
[image]

I have tried implementing gutters as per the [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/) however nothing seems to introduce the spacing required.

Any guidance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put the styling `border rounded bg-light` in the wrong element. The styling should be put on the element within the `.col`.

`.col` class use `padding` CSS to produce the horizontal spacing and `padding` is within the `border` of element, that's the reason why your current styling didn't work.

Hope it helps and Happy coding !

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<h5 class="text-center text-decoration-underline">Original Result</h5>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">

     <!-- LEFT -->
     <div class="col-md-4 border rounded bg-light">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
           <h5 class="text-center"> Some text here </h5>
        </div>
        <br>
     </div>

     <!-- RIGHT -->
     <div class="col-md-4 border rounded bg-white">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
           <h3 class="text-center"> Some text here</h3>
           <h2 class="text-center">Some text here</h2>
           <p class="text-center" style="font-size: 11px;">Some text here</p>
        </div>
     </div>
     <br>
  </div>
</div>

<h5 class="text-center text-decoration-underline">Restructured Result</h5>
<div class="container mt-3">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
  
    <!-- LEFT -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="border rounded bg-light h-100">
         <h5 class="text-center"> Some text here </h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>

    <!-- RIGHT -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="border rounded bg-white h-100">
        <h3 class="text-center"> Some text here</h3>
        <h2 class="text-center">Some text here</h2>
        <p class="text-center" style="font-size: 11px;">Some text here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This works in regular sizing but when the breakpoint changes to mobile responsive the, i.e. stacked vertically, the gap is removed again.

Comment: I gather this is because I need a bottom margin on the columns?

Comment: Achieved this by adding 'col-md-4 mb-4 mb-md-0'

Comment: @jimiclapton Yes, you need sort of `margin-bottom` CSS to achieve that, glad that you had found out the way, keep your passion mate, happy coding :)